# Why $\nabla_{\theta} \log p(y;\theta) = \frac{\nabla_{\theta}p(y;\theta)}{p(y;\theta)}$?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, information-theory, kullback-leibler, fisher-information

I'm solving a problem for cs 229, problem description in below when i check the answer it mentioned the given equation, but I don't undertand why is that.

[image]

I want to know why, anyone give me some sort of proof?

$$\nabla_{\theta} \log p(y;\theta) = \frac{\nabla_{\theta}p(y;\theta)}{p(y;\theta)}$$

Comment: This is a result that comes from a fact taught in first-semester calculus. Please tag as [tag:self-study] because this is a homework or exam problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without giving too much away as this is a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question: let $f(\theta) = p(y; \theta)$ so that you simplify some of the notation and make it more familiar-looking.

$$
\nabla_\theta \log f(\theta) = \frac{\nabla_\theta f(\theta)}{f(\theta)}
$$

That's a bit less cluttered. Now it might be easier to see *how* we can use a rule from first-year calculus.

Comment: I still don't understand. What is the name of this rule? Does it same with derivative of ln(x) w.r.t x? then i know it's $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: $(\ln f(x))'=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$

Comment: Understand! Thanks! forgot the notation..$\frac{d}{d\theta}\log(f(\theta)) = \frac{1}{f(\theta)} \cdot \frac{d}{d\theta}f(\theta)$